# Why do i get command prompt "... is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, c++

I got this problem as described by the link below,

[C++ Hello World not showing output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33845355/c-hello-world-not-showing-output/)

and I was suggested to try opening the file using command prompt.
Here was what i did,

[Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB6WW.png)

Is that how we run an exe. using command prompt? Or I have misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is command prompt does not know anything about spaces in file names.

it thinks your exe name is FLTK and testing as a paramter to your application.

if you try "FLTK Testing.exe" with quotes as written it will probably run.

but i suggest that renaming your exe without spaces for easy access.

also if you press F and Tab probably command prompt encapsulates file name in quotes (") automatically.